# Sort order in Nautilus: Phonebook-style

Tags: nautilus

I want Nautilus to sort in a [phonebookstyle](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=de_US_POSIX&d_=en&x=col&collation=phonebook), e.g. underscores should be first:

```
_Anton
_Bert
_Caesar
Anton
Bert
Caesar
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose "Sort By Name" from the context menu, this should give you what you are looking for (AFAIK).

Please note that the results may not be 100% to your liking, depending on the sorting algorithm used by Nautilus.